# Facebook SDK's logInWithPublishPermissions stucks with everlasting spinner

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to ask the user of my android app the permission to publish on facebook when a custom share button (it's just an ImageView) is pressed. On button's `OnClick` method I execute this block:

```
CallbackManager facebookCallbackManager;    

...

facebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(facebookCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                shareContent(activity, content, true);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancel() { }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) { }
        });
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(activity, Collections.singletonList("publish_actions"));
```

And then I override:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    facebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The problem is that the request never comes: an everlasting spinner wheel is presented and no callback (nor success, nor cancel, nor error) is called.

a. The user is already logged in, according to:

```
public static boolean isLoggedIn() {
   AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
   return accessToken != null;
}
```

b. `FacebookSdk.isInitialized()` is true

c. Publish permissions are *not* granted, according to:

```
private static boolean hasPublishPermissions() {
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    return accessToken != null && accessToken.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
}
```

d. Other uses of FB SDK are used through the app and they are functioning.

e. I am an app admin on FB dashboard

Any idea on the problem?

**Important PS:**

Since Facebook's API is extremely stable, depending on the time of the day or the position of the stars, without changing code **I have three possible outcomes**:

1. As described before, an everlasting spinner wheel.
2. The callback fires the `onCancel` method without the user interaction.
3. It shares the content without asking for confirmation - this gave me a nice unwanted video posted on my personal FB, without me noticing :) -

   PS2:
   Even the classic `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermission`now is having the same issue. It never had it before.

Answer (score 3):

then you can share content without everlasting spinner

```
 LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManagerFacebook, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            System.out.println("Success");
            if (loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions().contains("publish_actions")) {
                new shareContent(activity, content, true);

            }  else {
                //Toast.makeText(youractivity.this, "Successfully Connected to Facebook.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                GetFacebookPublishPermissions();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            //Log.d(TAG_CANCEL, "On cancel");
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(youractivity.this, "Looks like we are unable to connect to Facebook Servers.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            // Log.d(TAG_ERROR, error.toString());
        }
    });
```

and getFacebookSharepermission

```
 public void GetFacebookPublishPermissions(){
    if(LoginManager.getInstance()!=null)
    {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(youractivity.this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));

    }
}
```

> Update

you can call this function like below

```
      AccessToken token = com.facebook.AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if(token!=null)
        {
            if (token.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")) {
            new shareContent(activity, content, true);
        }else{
        GetFacebookPublishPermissions();
        }
   }else{
         LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, 
         Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday"));
   }
```

Comment: I'll try this as soon as possible, but just reading the code: If I register the callback without actually calling anything else, when is the code in `onSuccess` called?

Comment: I updated my code . you can use updated code to initiate onSuccess

Comment: Same exact problem with your code, now even with `logInWithReadPermissions` (so, onSuccess is not triggered and logInWithPublishPermissions isn't called)

Comment: did you submit review in fb for publish or are you sure you are login with  registered developer account in fb developer console

Comment: I am an app admin - some other facebook functions work -, but I didn't submit review: but it shouldn't be needed for this kind of permission, should it? It worked since last week without

Answer (score 0):

I think there is mistake for callback manager.
you declare and assign CallbackManager facebookCallbackManager;
facebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

Here you can see there is **cbManager** instead of **facebookCallbackManager** 
 so please double check for that.

```
                                                V
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(cbManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            shareContent(activity, content, true);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() { }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) { }
    });
```

Comment: True, that was definitively an error (due to the thousands of attempts I did in changing the code!)
Unfortunately, that was not _the error_, problem is still there :(